# Performance of xml path

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query below:

```
select col1,
       col2,
       .
       .
       .
       coln
  from table1
  left join table2
  on some condition
  .
  .
  left  join tablen
  on some condition
  left join (
              select t1.col1,
              (
                select t2.col2 + ';' as [data()]
                  from SomeTable t2
                 where t2.col1 = t1.col1
                 for xml path('')
              ) value
              from SomeTable t1
              group by t1.Col1
            )MyTable
         on some condition
```

The above query will return about 4000 rows. The inline select statement using xml path will also result in about 4000 records.

I wish to know if there will be any performance impact with this query due to the use of xml path.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless and untill you have proper indexes on the all joining columns in left join and proper covering indexes in select list of columns,there wont be any performance issue here.